# using Liouville-Ostrogradsky to solve differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, derivatives, continuity, wronskian

I have a differential equation:
$$y''+p_1\left(x\right)y'+p_0\left(x\right)y=0$$
for $x>0$ and it is given that $p_0,p_1$ are continuous for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

I am questioned if $y_1(x)=x$ and $y_2(x)=\ln(x)$ can be the solutions of this equation.

Answer:
They are linear independent, therefore using Liouville-Ostrogradsky:
$$W(y_1,y_2)(x)=ce^{-\int \:p_1\left(x\right)dx}$$
we get:
$$W(y_1,y_2)(x)=\left|\begin{pmatrix}x&\ln\left(x\right)\\ 1&\frac{1}{x}\end{pmatrix}\right|=\ln\left(x\right)-1$$
so, we can choose c=1 for comfort and get:
$$\ln\left(x\right)-1=e^{-\int p_1\left(x\right)dx}$$
therefore:
$$\int p_1\left(x\right)dx=\frac{1}{\ln\left(\ln\left(x\right)-1\right)}$$
Therefore, after deriving both sides:
$$p_1\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{x\cdot \left(\ln\left(x\right)-1\right)\cdot \ln^2\left(\ln\left(x\right)-1\right)}$$

Now the thing that bothers me, that is was said about $p_1$ that it is continuous for $x\in \mathbb{R}, x>0$, and here the denominator is defined only for any $x>e$, so I don't know if the authors of the question meant that it should be continuous for any $x>e$ and then we can continue and find $p_0$ or it contradicts the given statement and therefore those two functions cannot be a solution for the equation.

Am I right that those are the two options of answers for this diff. equation ?
If it is about $x>e$, then we can choose $$y=x+\ln(x)$$, calculate $y'$ and $y''$, put it all together in the first formula: $y''+p_1\left(x\right)y'+p_0\left(x\right)y=0$ and extract $p_0$.

Otherwise if the question means that $p_1(x)$ has to be continuous on $x>0$, then $p_1(x)$ doesn't satisfies that because it is defined only for $x>e$, is this correct ?

Answer (score 2):

If $t_1,y_2$ are two linearly independent solutions of a second order ODE. This ODE is given by: $$\begin{vmatrix} y'' & y'& y \\ y_1'' & y_1' & y_1 \\ y_2'' & y_2' & y_2 \end{vmatrix}=0$$ Here we have$$\begin{vmatrix} y'' & y'& y \\0 & 1 & x \\ -1/x^2 & 1/x & \ln x \end{vmatrix}=0$$
$$\implies (\ln x-1)y''-\frac{1}{x}y'+\frac{1}{x^2}y=0$$
So $$p_1(x)=(x(1-\ln x))^{-1}, p_0(x)=(x^2(\ln x-1))^{-1}$$

Comment: I don't understand the final conclusions from those calculations. We get $p_0, p_1$ which are not continuous on $x>0$, this means that those $y_0,y_1$ can not be the solutions for this equation, as much as I can tell.

Answer (score 2):

You could short-circuit the task from the start. Any solution, if not artificially restricted, has the whole of $\Bbb R$ as domain, as the coefficients are assumed as continuous everywhere. With the restriction to the positive half axis, this still gives a finite limit for $x\to0$, as in the extended solution this also is a point of continuity. Thus you can not get a solution $y=\ln x$ or $y=\ln|x|$ with its singularity at $x=0$.

Comment: So, in ZA's answer, the conclusion is those p's aren't continuous, thus $x$ and $ln(x)$ cannot be the solutions (singularity at $x=e$)?

Comment: This is additional, the singularity at $x=0$ remains also in this more detailed computation. Either singularity gives a contradiction. I added a remark on the restriction to the half axis, a singularity at $x=0$ is not possible if the coefficients are continuous there.